# Time to wait for sending data after sync ack sent in TCP

Tags: tcp

I am learning more about the internet and TCP/IP in my spare time since I was woefully inept at its operation.

I used the WinPCAP dll Wireshark uses, and eventually wrote entire modules for implementing ARP, IPV4, UDP, DHCP client, DNS client, ICMP, LLMNR (partial server), and now I'm working on TCP/IP.

TCP/IP is much bigger it seems than all previously mentioned protocols and I'm trying to understand it.

One item I'm trying to figure out is the time a client is able to send data to the server after the connection has been established.  Take the below example.

1. Client sends Server a TCP SYNC packet.
2. Server sends Client a TCP ACK/SYNC packet.
3. Client sends Server a TCP ACK packet.
   How long does the client have to wait to send the server data after step 3?
   Theoretically if the client sends data to the server right after the ACK, the data could show up to the server before the ACK (unlikely, but possible).

What is the recommended time to elapse before sending data?
I could not find this in any example or the RFC.

Comment: Zero. The client doesn't have to wait at all. In fact if it is quick enough the ACK can be piggybacked onto the first data segment. TCP is not delivered out of order.

Comment: What I'm worried about is that in step three if the client sends out the ACK and in another packet sends out some data right after, isn't it possible that the data arrives to the server before the ACK due to potential issues with the routing of the data?  In writing this I think I've come to the conclusion that it wouldn't matter anyways.  The server should discard the data, not supply an ACK to the data since the connection wasn't established.  At which point the client should timeout out on the packet sent and resend the data.